# $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I know that:

$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

But what is:

$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a~\cdot~ x^2} dx = ?~~~~~~\text{where }a>0$$

Comment: Change the variable $ax^2=(x\sqrt a)^2=>z=x\sqrt a$

Comment: Hint: Let $u=x \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: And the first  integral is $I=\frac 12 \sqrt \pi $ not $1/4$

Comment: its only half of the distribution...

Comment: $e^{-ax^2} \ne e^{-a} e^{x^2}$, instead $e^{-a+x^2}=e^{-a} e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Besides the fact that this insight was wrong, what do you have against "doing the obvious" ?

Comment: @Dunkelheit ok...good point...  also, good point LostinSpace... i'll fix the posting..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ to evaluate

$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} dx = \frac1{\sqrt a}\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\sqrt a x)^2} d(\sqrt ax)=\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi a}$$